# Are my already installed PIP Packages moved to my virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip

Say that I downloaded PyGame via pip. If I create a virtual environment, will PyGame be downloaded to that virtual environment or must I use os.system("pip install PyGame")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you created the virtualenv.

If you've specified `--system-site-packages` option, the system installed libraries will be available for import.

If you didn't specify it, they will not be, which is the default behaviour.